# Operator overloading with == != > <

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return numerator + "/" + denominator;
        }
        class TestRational
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                Rational x, y, z;
                x = new Rational(7, 4);
                y = new Rational(2, 3);
                z = x ‐ y;
                Console.WriteLine(x + " ‐ " + y + " = " + z);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i need to convert this code to again operator overloading function but for operands == != < > this are turning bool value i couldn't found correct way pls help

```
public static bool operator ==(Rational op1, Rational op2)
        {
            bool status = false;
            if (op1 == op2)
            {
                status = true;
            }
            return status;
        }
```

this way is correct ?

Comment: i have to show this rational numbers with operands  == != < > using operator overloading

Comment: Right, but did you try to write code for those operators?  If so, show us what you tried and tell us why it didn't work.  Include any compilation errors, exceptions, or failed test cases.  Basically SO is not a place to just ask people to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static bool operator ==(Rational op1, Rational op2)
    {
        return op1.numerator * op2.denominator == op1.denominator * op2.numerator;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Rational op1, Rational op2)
    {
        return op1.numerator * op2.denominator != op1.denominator * op2.numerator;
    }
    public static bool operator <(Rational op1, Rational op2)
    {
        return op1.numerator * op2.denominator < op1.denominator * op2.numerator;
    }
    public static bool operator >(Rational op1, Rational op2)
    {
        return op1.numerator * op2.denominator > op1.denominator * op2.numerator;
    }
```

Comment: how about my `Console.WriteLine `

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString() + " ‐ " + y.ToString() + " = " + z.ToString());`

Comment: i did this way   `Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1} = {2}", x, y, x == y);` its working

Comment: Yes that's because `{0}` and `{1}` calls `public override string ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have a circular logic problem, that will result in an infinite loop.  You have defined how to compare two `Rational` objects with the the `==` operator, but then you use that operator in the code.  Instead you need to define what makes two `Rational`s equal.  Maybe it's as simple as this:

```
public static bool operator ==(Rational op1, Rational op2)
{
   return op1.numerator == op2.numerator && op1.denominator == op2.denominator;
}
```

Of course that would not say that 1/2 and 2/4 are equal, but you'll have to decide what logic to implement here.  You can then use the `==` operator when defining the `!=` operator, but you just need to make sure you do not end up with any type of circular logic, like using `==` in the `!=` and `!=` in the `==`.